# what is the difference between campaign member "Member First Associated Date" and campaign member "Created date"?

Tags: date, campaign-member

what is the difference between campaign member "Member First Associated Date" and campaign member "Created date"?

Object: Campaign Member

Answer (score 1):

The Member First Associated Date is when the user was first added to a particular campaign. The Created Date is a Date/Time field that just notes when the campaign member record was created.

Comment: When a member is added to a campaign isn't it associated with a campaign ? So what how is the associated date different ?

Comment: Agreed.  CreatedDate is a standard database field, so it'll appear on every object regardless of how redundant it may seem.   Also, if you are migrating data from a legacy system (audit fields enabled), you can enter a historical value for CreatedDate, thereby causing CreatedDate to not exactly equal    MemberFirstAssociatedDate.

Comment: @SalesDriver they are really the same. Just different names and different descriptions but other than that there isn't a difference.

Comment: @BlairKristin But the dates are different why is that so ?

Comment: @SalesDriver what are the dates for each one as an example?

Comment: @BlairKristin A sample Created date is 5/12/2014 and the first associated date is 2/5/2015. (Date format in my comment is MM/DD/YYYY)

Comment: @SalesDriver these dates can be the same but when they are different it is because the a Campaign Member can be associated with more than one campaign.

Answer (score 0):

We use a Process Builder and custom fields to mimic the behavior of the report column. It runs on creates and edits of Campaign Members. If the CM has a Lead ID, (it may not, the member could be a Contact or who knows what), and if that Lead's Camp_Name__c doesn't match the campaign member's Campaign's Name field, it stores:

- the campaign's Name field to the Lead's Camp Name field,
- the campaign's Type field to the Lead's Camp Type field, and
- the formula Now() to the Lead's Camp Date field.

So we always have the date on which the Lead most recently began its association with a campaign, and the name and type of that campaign. Previous associations are forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this - at least in Custom Reports using the Created Date on Campaign Member, and indeed this field does NOT show the date the campaign member was created.

Here is Salesforce's response to the case I created:
Campaign Member Created Date is the date when the contact/lead was created. You need to use the field called Member First Associated Date in the report to see the actual date when the campaign member was created or when the lead/contact was added as member of the campaign.